# How to call export function, bypassing interactive menu

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-export

The shortcut `C-c C-e` is linked to `org-export-dispatch`. Whenever I want to export my current org buffer as `html`, I do `C-c C-e R R`, which is `Export to reveal.js HTML Presentation -> To File`. I am working on a presentation and I will be doing this dozens of times in the coming days. I would like to have my own keyboard shortcut to hit that export method.

Doing this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<")     'org-export-dispatch)
```

Will allow me to reach the interactive menu of `org-export-dispatch`, but I still need to select `R -> R`.

How can I embed that selection into the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-<")     'org-reveal-export-to-html)` should do the trick. There are more options. Just look at the end of [ox-reveal.el](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/master/ox-reveal.el).

Comment: @Tobias great, that is perfect. Could you put it is as answer, so that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the call to [`org-export-define-derived-backend`](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/1cdd088ec5fab631c564dca7f9f74fd3e9b7d4d4/ox-reveal.el#L37) in org-mode exporters like [`ox-reveal`](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/master/ox-reveal.el).

The exporter submenu is defined there as property `:menu-entry`.

In the case of `ox-reveal` you find:

```el
(org-export-define-derived-backend 'reveal 'html

  :menu-entry
  '(?R "Export to reveal.js HTML Presentation"
       ((?R "To file" org-reveal-export-to-html)
        (?B "To file and browse" org-reveal-export-to-html-and-browse)
        (?S "Current subtree to file" org-reveal-export-current-subtree)))
...
)
```

This tells you that the key sequence `C-c C-e R R` is bound to `org-reveal-export-to-html`.

You can bind it to a shorter keysequence if you like:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'org-reveal-export-to-html)
```